# How to look through a phrase in a dictionary?

Tags: python, django, algorithm, search, recursion

I have a structure:

```
{
    "content": "Name 1", 
    "name": "directory", 
    "decendent": [
         {
            "content": "Name 2", 
            "name": "subdirectory", 
            "decendent": None
        }, 
        {
            "content": "Name 3", 
            "name": "subdirectory_two", 
            "decendent": [
                {
                    "content": "Name 4", 
                    "name": "subsubdirectory", 
                    "decendent": None
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have to look for the sequence of words which are typed in the search field:

```
 <form id="tfnewsearch" method="get" action="/help/search">
        <input type="text" class="tftextinput" name="q" size="21" maxlength="120">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="tfbutton">
 </form>
```

and if I found it - add them to

```
   [
        {
             "content": "The sought content",
             "phrase": "the sought phrase",
             "name": "unique name"
        }, ...
   ]
```

for each found  coincidence.

E.g.:
If I look for "I have", i should get:

```
 [
       {
            "content": "I have a good day", 
            "phrase": "I have", 
            "name": "subdirectory", 

        },
        {
            "content": "While I have several ways to do it",
            "phrase": "I have", 
            "name": "subdirectory2"
        },
        {
            "content": "When I had it",
            "phrase": "I have",
            "name": "subdirectory3"
         },
 ]
```

How to implement it in Python using recursion in case if I'm going to change this phrase in the process of the search using morphological analyzer like pymorhph2 (in example: "have", "had")?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I added it to the description

Comment: Fixed it. You can read again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know pymorph2, but you could do:

```
def f1(a, s):
    if s in a["contents"]:
        a["phrase"] = s
    for b in a["descendent"]:
        f(b, s)
```

Where the argument **a** is your main dictionary, and **s** the phrase to look for.

However, in case you call **f** again, it will erase the preceding value. If it's not what you want, you may consider instead, for example:

```
def f2(a, s):
    if s in a["contents"]:
        if "phrase" not in a:
            a["phrase"] = [s]
        else:
            a["phrase"].append(s)
    for b in a["descendent"]:
        f(b, s)
```

If you want to also return a list of matching dictionaries:

```
def f3(a, s):
    r = []
    if s in a["contents"]:
        if "phrase" not in a:
            a["phrase"] = [s]
        else:
            a["phrase"].append(s)
        r.append(a)
    for b in a["descendent"]:
        r += f(b, s)
    return r
```

If you want to copy data in the output list instead of only references to the original dictionaries, you can replace `r.append(a)` with, for example

```
r.append({k: a[k] for k in ("content", "phrase", "name")})
```

Comment: But if I'd like to return a list of dictionaries? 
E.g.: res = [res] + f(d2, name) if res:  return res

Comment: @paus Edited. Do you want to return a list of all matching dictionaries, or only fresh dictionaries with only the needed data? I mean, as is, f3 won't remove descendents, but it should not be a problem.

Comment: Only fresh dictionaries with only the needed data with no descendents in body, as I think. Because in my case the content - is the content of html file, it can be huge by size.

Comment: @paud Notice they are only pointers, nothing is duplicated in the process. There is even less duplication if you don't build fresh dictionaries (you put only pointers in your list, no new data). And it will be necessary if you want to modify them inside your main structure afterwards. It really depends on what you want to do.

Comment: I would like to list it in the search results. So I don't know really if the modification is needed in this process, but duplication of data may be expensive.